# iOS Core Data NSInternalInconsistencyException Error in second Storyboard-View

Tags: ios, core-data, storyboard

I trying to get into the whole CoreData thing. I started using the raw Example which you get when starting a clean "Master-Detail-View" with storyboard and Coredata.

1. I edited the coredata-model and created a second "table".
2. I copied the MasterViewController changing the @"Strings" in the fetchedResultsController

When I build&run, the app crashes when switching to the modified masterviewcontroller. the original masterviewcontroller works fine!

datasource in storyboard is linked.

Additional info:
    'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an
    NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'RaumType''

Comment: Is there anything on the console?

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'RaumType''

Comment: i've done a whole new project from the start, error isn't in it any more, don't know and don't care what and why ;)